# Writing script that make numbered list of every writable normal type file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to make some kind of hdguard script. I'm stuck, beacause I have to make a numbered list of all writable normal type files (no link directories etc.). List has to include only names and sizes of files. Then I have to choose files that I want to delete by numbers.

I tried every kind of `ls` function and `find` function, but there no way that satisfy me.

```
ls -Ss1pq --block-size=1
```

is the closest I can get, but it doesn't display files in subdirectories and display directories (have to display only writable files).

Desired output:

```
1. [size] [filename]
2. [size2] [filename2]
...
```

After I have chosen for example "1", the script has to make txt file with list of paths to every chosen file.

So, I've got this

```
find /homee -type f -not -path '/\.*' |sort -r -n -k7
```

It gets better

```
find /homee -type f - ls -not -path '/\.*' -exec du -hs {} + |sort -r -n -k7
```

but how to display only names not path?

i can also go with

```
find /homee -type f -not -path '/\.*' -exec du -hs {} + |sort -r -n -k7 |sed 's/.*\///' | nl
```

but now there no file sizes
what should i do?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Why does find not work?

Comment: i use find but there is a lot of hidden files that i don't need.

Comment: [How to exclude/ignore hidden files and directories in a wildcard-embedded “find” search?](https://askubuntu.com/q/266179/336375)

Comment: You really want _to make txt file with list of paths to every chosen file_ after each time you have chosen one file?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to enter line numbers to a file, is to use `grep -n` on an empty string, as you can see here:

```
Prompt> cat testtttt.txt
First line
Second line
Third line
Prompt> grep -n "" testtttt.txt
1:First line
2:Second line
3:Third line
```

`-n` adds the line number where the entry is found, and by searching for an empty string (which you can find on every line), you get a kind of line numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4+ can use `mapfile` to generate an array from standard input. `select` is a tool for generating menus. `Ctrl`+`D` to exit.

```
mapfile -t Files < <(
  find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' \
         -exec du -h {} + |sort -r
)
select f in "${Files[@]##*$'\t'}"; do rm -i "$f"; done
```

The output of `du` is tab-delimited, so `"${Files[@]##*$'\t'}"`:

- `${Files[@]}` - All elements of array `Files`
- `${variable##pattern}` - Subtract all left-most occurrences of `pattern` from `variable`
- `*$'\t'` - anything followed by a literal tab